# How Do I Set the Speed that a C# Timer Counts Down or Stopwatch Counts Up?

Tags: c#, timer

Let's say I'm making a game where I want Timers or Stopwatches to slow down in response to slowmo effects. How do I go about doing that? Looking at the API docs, there doesn't seem to be any way to scale the rate that they do their thing, so I was wondering if there's some other trick I can use to get the same effect.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? A bit more context would be helpful.

Comment: @YungDeiza I want to make it so Timers and Stopwatches can change the rate they they tick. For example, if I set a time scale to 0.5, then a Timer will count down half as quickly. If the scale is instead 1.5, then it counts down 50% faster than normal. The idea is so that when some slowmo effect is applied in the game, a Timer can slow itself down with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the interval to part of its original value and use some variable to keep track of the elapsed time
Like this:

```
int counter = 0;
int scale = 2; //scaling factor
int originalInterval = 1000;

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = originalInterval / scale;
timer.Tick += (sender, e) => {
    counter++;
    if (counter >= scale) {
        // perform the needed action here
        counter = 0; // reset the counter
    }
};
```

If you want to use a stopwatch, then like this:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

int scale = 2;

stopwatch.Start();

while (true) {
    //Scale the elapsed time and by the factor
    double elapsed = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / scale;

    //When the scaled elapsed time exceeds a threshold
    if (elapsed > threshold) {
        // perform the needed action here
        break;
    }
}
```